# XML layout display Order

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have more than one XML-layout  on my app and i am looking for a way to change the order in which my XML-layout displays when  running   my app 
like which one of the  layouts is displayed first ?

Comment: i guess you are trying to create some dynamic view kind of thing. cam you explain war exactly you are doing so that you can get most optimized amswers

Answer (score 0):

I think I didn't understand your question exactly but you can have as many as layouts you want. your activity shows the layout inside **oncreate** with **setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout)**. If you want some particular parts in your layout, you can use [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).